# Create ReadStream And Uploade Files to a Remote Server via multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

So I Want Upload Large File To Remote,So I Am Creating ReadStream

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(req.file.path);

async uploadStream(stream: NodeJS.ReadableStream, filePath: string) {
        const dir = path.dirname(filePath);
        if (!(await this.exists(dir))) {
            await this.mkdir(dir);
        }

        await this.putStream(stream, filePath);
        return this.url(filePath);
    }



async putStream(stream: NodeJS.ReadableStream, filePath: string) {
        await this.connect();
        const normFIlePath = this.normalizePath(filePath);
        await this.sftp.put(stream, normFIlePath).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
        await this.disconnect()
    }
```

After Upload I Am Saving data to database and returing file url

```
file = await fileRepo.save(file);
res.send({
            id: file.data.itemId,
            src: file.url
        });
```

File is Uploading But After That it's return errors:

```
(node:18) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Comment: I tried
 res.send({]);
 return;

same result.

Comment: Why would you like to create a readable stream in the first place? Isn't multer enough for this task?

Comment: @lekinio
`Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error occurs if you send res.send() response multiple times. You should use res.write() if you want to send a continuous stream response

Comment: @LuisOrbaiceta I delete stream but it is same results.I add console.logs for debugging and while video is uploading its return error: Http failure: 0 Unknown Error and after that  its stuck for a while and then i i see console.logs and that ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error

Comment: and its happens only large files.